# Split long text into paragraphs on EOL and <p> tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to split a long text into paragraphs in order to do some manipulation.

The goals:

1. Split long text into paragraphs based on any combination of newline characters, `<p>`, and `<p id="" class="" style="">` (any combination of id, class, or style).
2. Retain the `<p` tags for when I put it back together

Here's what I have so far:

```
$paragraphs = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r|<p?>/', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Here are the issues with it:

1. It doesn't capture `<p class="">`
2. It doesn't retain the `<p` tag

Is there a way to accomplish this using preg_split?

UPDATED Example:

Incoming content may be:

```
<p class="example">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in odio ac diam interdum vulputate eget vel nisl. Aliquam felis nulla, porttitor ac elit eu, auctor blandit metus. Sed ut turpis quam. Fusce fermentum felis nec nulla hendrerit, sit amet euismod lectus hendrerit. Nullam malesuada est urna, non iaculis enim rhoncus sit amet. Vivamus metus arcu, consectetur at nisi vitae, suscipit finibus purus. Pellentesque pellentesque sapien mauris, ac dignissim ipsum rhoncus vitae. Proin nulla leo, ultrices ut diam in, condimentum efficitur urna.</p><p>Mauris felis felis, condimentum sed nisl commodo, suscipit commodo magna. Donec quis diam vel nibh commodo facilisis. Sed pretium purus non mi dapibus sagittis. Sed sed rutrum odio.</p>

Integer quis condimentum lectus. Pellentesque tristique ultrices nisi a auctor. Donec porta molestie dignissim. <p>Integer ut enim eget felis molestie ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus a venenatis turpis, sit amet commodo nulla. Aliquam nunc ligula, imperdiet sed eleifend a, convallis ut leo.</p> Praesent pharetra finibus quam, quis viverra augue blandit non. Ut commodo finibus dolor at volutpat. Etiam id elit cursus, luctus augue ac, iaculis purus. Vivamus posuere ex vitae orci dictum, consequat tincidunt lorem molestie. Fusce nec erat quis nibh pretium convallis. In pretium euismod augue at interdum. Sed magna elit, pellentesque sed elit eget, venenatis imperdiet dolor.
```

Needed array in $paragraphs:

```
$paragraphs = array(
    0 => '<p class="example">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in odio ac diam interdum vulputate eget vel nisl. Aliquam felis nulla, porttitor ac elit eu, auctor blandit metus. Sed ut turpis quam. Fusce fermentum felis nec nulla hendrerit, sit amet euismod lectus hendrerit. Nullam malesuada est urna, non iaculis enim rhoncus sit amet. Vivamus metus arcu, consectetur at nisi vitae, suscipit finibus purus. Pellentesque pellentesque sapien mauris, ac dignissim ipsum rhoncus vitae. Proin nulla leo, ultrices ut diam in, condimentum efficitur urna.</p>',
    1 => '<p>Mauris felis felis, condimentum sed nisl commodo, suscipit commodo magna. Donec quis diam vel nibh commodo facilisis. Sed pretium purus non mi dapibus sagittis. Sed sed rutrum odio.</p>',
    2 => 'Integer quis condimentum lectus. Pellentesque tristique ultrices nisi a auctor. Donec porta molestie dignissim.',
    3 => '<p>Integer ut enim eget felis molestie ultrices. Cum sociis natoque       penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus a venenatis turpis, sit amet commodo nulla. Aliquam nunc ligula, imperdiet sed eleifend a, convallis ut leo.</p> Praesent pharetra finibus quam, quis viverra augue blandit non. Ut commodo finibus dolor at volutpat. Etiam id elit cursus, luctus augue ac, iaculis purus. Vivamus posuere ex vitae orci dictum, consequat tincidunt lorem molestie. Fusce nec erat quis nibh pretium convallis. In pretium euismod augue at interdum. Sed magna elit, pellentesque sed elit eget, venenatis imperdiet dolor.'
);
```

Comment: post an input and expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added an example actual and expected from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a very simple workaround, you could add a line break before any `<p [...]` and `<p>`:

```
$content = str_replace("<p>", "\n<p>", $content);
$content = str_replace("<p ", "\n<p ", $content);
```

Then you use your `preg_split`:

```
$paragraphs = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

So you capture any `<p [...]>` and the `<p>`s are retained inside the paragraphs.

Comment: Nice one. Indeed simple but effective

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
$para = preg_split('~(?<=</p>)\s*|(?!\G)\s*(?=<p)~', trim($text));
```

the separator is described as a position preceded by a closing p tag that can match zero or more whitespace characters.

`(?<=...)` is a lookbehind and means *preceded by*. Note that a lookbehind is only a test and that the content matched inside is not a part of the whole match

`\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters.

`\G` is an anchor for the end of the previous match result

Note: if you want to take newlines in account as paragraph separator, you can change the pattern to:

```
$para = preg_split('~(?<=</p>)\s*|(?!\G)\s*(?=<p)|\h*+\s+~', trim($text));
```

But note that in this case the text enclosed between p tags must not contain newline characters to have a coherent result.

Comment: I need to mention, that this is a valid answer to the intentional question - unlike mine. Unfortunately lookbehinds are beyond my regexp skills.